# Unable to revive interactive reverse shell using Python

Tags: python, linux, terminal, pty, stty

I've been working on the Scriptkiddie box on Hack the Box and have got to the point of upgrading a dumb to interactive shell step using python. The suggested way to do this is the same as the final example here: https://blog.ropnop.com/upgrading-simple-shells-to-fully-interactive-ttys/

However I get to the point of bringing back my shell to the foreground with `fg` but from that point I'm unable to execute any commands. Pressing enter just displays `^M`:

```
┌──(kali㉿kali)-[~]
└─$ sudo nc -nlvp 443                                                                                                  1 ⨯
listening on [any] 443 ...
connect to [10.10.14.2] from (UNKNOWN) [10.10.10.226] 58996
whoami
kid
python3 -c 'import pty;pty.spawn("/bin/bash")'
kid@scriptkiddie:~/html$ ^Z
zsh: suspended  sudo nc -nlvp 443
                                                                                                                           
┌──(kali㉿kali)-[~]
└─$ stty raw -echo                                                                                               148 ⨯ 1 ⚙
                                                                                                                           
┌──(kali㉿kali)-[~]
                   └─$                                                                                                     fg⚙
[1]  + continued  sudo nc -nlvp 443
                                   reset^M^M
```

(`fg` is typed after executing the stty line). Does anyone know what's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

Turned out this was because kali doesnt use bash as default, rather zshell. Switching to bash before starting the process prevents this behaviour.